# MSSQL: How to monitor stored procedure execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it somehow possible to monitor stored procedure execution time? I would like to automatically execute one stored procedure multiple times during the day and would like to save these results somewhere to analyze them later?

Comment: well since you are executing it... you could just make note of it each time you execute it... or SET STATISTICS TIME ON and store the results...

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck using the MSSQL Profiler: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler

I believe it comes bundled with MSSQL Express.

Comment: Profiler is deprecated (and is a drag on performance). The replacement is Extended Events.

Comment: Was not aware it had been deprecated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not only the whole proc execution time, but you can log even each statement execution time for more procedures.

First create a log table containing for example proc_name, statement, begin/end time, rows_affected, ...

Then in your procedures save the StartTime into a variable just before every statement execution, and after the statement insert into log table values (proc_name, statement, @StartTime, getdate(), @@rowcount).

Then you can analyze top (10) long-running statements/corresponding procedures like this:

```
 select top 10 *
 from dbo.log
 order by datediff(ss, StartTime, EndTime) desc
```

It's usefull for procs such as ETL procs that are executing every day (but not every second) and you can even log the errors

Comment: this makes sence, but I need to investigate a bit more, how to actually make it work.
I give you a little bit more detailed information, what I try to accomplish, maybe you can give some more advise:

I execute one certain command in stored procedure with some randome values, not the whole stored procedure. 
I enter diferent products id to gather product information. If I execute it manually I see how long it takes, but I would like to automate this, that it will automatically execute with randomly chosen id and saves the execution time somewhere.

Comment: If you can to change the procedure text, just add the insert statements into a log table

Comment: I updated my comment, I pressed the enter for new line and unintentionally saved it.

Comment: Those values are sp parameters passed 1 at the time, or you should exec your command inside this proc many times in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

alroc, has mentioned it but the 'modern' way to do this is with the Extended Events.  No new tables, no profiler, no mess.